# WinRM HTTPS - Certificate: the specified credentials were rejected by the server

Tags: windows, https, ansible, certificate, winrm

We have a few servers where the WinRM authentication is failing using the local admin account and the certificate because of the rejected credentials:

```
msg: certificate: the specified credentials were rejected by the server
```

Note that we have used the exact same setup on other servers and it works there. What's the issue/difference here compared to the other servers?

We have also tried all the known "workarounds" like adding the REG_DWORD "ClientAuthTrustMode" under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel" but it didn't help.
The WinRM HTTPS listener is properly configured and certificate authentication is allowed.

The error from the event log:

```
Provider Health: The WINRM certificate mapping configuration operation cannot be completed because the user credentials could not be verified.  Please check the username and password used for mapping this certificate and verify that it is a non-domain account and try again.

Details: 
    ProviderName=WSMan
    ExceptionClass=ProviderInvocationException
    ErrorCategory=InvalidOperation
    ErrorId=WsManError
    ErrorMessage=The WINRM certificate mapping configuration operation cannot be completed because the user credentials could not be verified.  Please check the username and password used for mapping this certificate and verify that it is a non-domain account and try again.
```

Any ideas?